# How do I format the X-Axis dates using UNIX Timestamp with CanvasJS

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

I am trying to create a candlestick graph with CanvasJs and I am currently having trouble formatting the X Axis correct to show the dates.

I am pulling this data from a database. When I pull the date from the data base I am pulling it as a UNIX Timestamp. I want the X-Axis to show the date for each data point (I want to just do it monthly but I'll worry about that later once I get this). I have tried using "label" and "x" for the date points on the X-Axis.

```
array_push($dataPoints, array("label"=>$row->day, "y"=> array($row->openPrice, $row->high, $row->low, $row->closePrice)));.
```

And here is what I have for creating the graph.
    window.onload = function() {

```
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            zoomEnabled:true,
            title: {
                text: "Apple Historical Prices"
            },
            axisX: {
                labelFormatter: function (e) {
                    return CanvasJS.formatDate( e.value, "DD MMM");
                },
                valueFormatString: "DD MMM"
            },
            axisY: {
                includeZero: false,
                prefix: "$"
            },
            data: [{
                type: "candlestick",
                xValueType: "dateTime",
                yValueFormatString: "$###.##",
                dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
            }]
        });
        chart.render();

        }
```

What would I have to change here to correctly format the X-Axis to show the date (convert from UNIX Time Stamp)

Currently it only displays "DEC 31" for each data point.

Answer (score 0):

Zack,

You are passing label and y-value to dataPoints whereas [xValueType](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/xvaluetype/) is applicable for [x-values](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/datapoints/x/). As you are not passing x-values in dataPoints, library auto-generates it as 1,2,3,4,5... which gives you undesired results in labelFormatter.

You can [convert Unix timestamp to JavaScript timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/847196) by multiplying it by 1000. Then pass that value as 'x' in dataPoints.

```
array_push($dataPoints, array("x"=>strtotime($row->day)*1000, "y"=> array($row->openPrice, $row->high, $row->low, $row->closePrice)));.
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but now that i have changed it to strtotime($row->day)*1000 it is still showing on the axis as Dec 31, however the date it shows when I hover over a data point shows "31 Dec 69" for each data point

Comment: Can you share sample data that you are passing to chart ($dataPoints)?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but here is a print out of the first few entries in $dataPoints  `Array ( [0] => Array ( [label] => 1049173200000 [y] => Array ( [0] => 1.010000 [1] => 1.020000 [2] => 1.000000 [3] => 1.010000 ) ) [1] => Array ( [label] => 1049259600000 [y] => Array ( [0] => 1.030000 [1] => 1.050000 [2] => 1.020000 [3] => 1.040000 ) ) [2] => Array ( [label] => 1049346000000 [y] => Array ( [0] => 1.040000 [1] => 1.050000 [2] => 1.030000 [3] => 1.030000 ) ) `